# Different result for Laravel's Eloquent And Raw Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Anyone experienced raw SQL queries having different results with eloquent?

Here is my eloquent returning a value:

```
BookingRoleSchedule::from('booking_role_schedules as a')
->whereExists(function ($q) {
  return $q
    ->select(DB::raw(1))
    ->from('booking_role_schedules as b')
    ->where('a.id', '<>', 'b.id')
    ->whereRaw('not(a.start_date >= b.end_date or a.end_date <= b.start_date)');
})
->join('booking_role_schedule_talent as c', function($join) {
    $join->on('a.id', '=', 'c.booking_role_schedule_id')
      ->whereExists(function($q) {
        return $q
          ->from('booking_role_schedule_talent as d')
          ->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->where('c.booking_role_schedule_id', '<>', 'd.booking_role_schedule_id')
          ->whereRaw('not(c.user_id != d.user_id)');
      });
})->get();
```

While my SQL query doesn't return any value

```
select *
from `booking_role_schedules` as `a`
       inner join `booking_role_schedule_talent` as `c` on `a`.`id` = `c`.`booking_role_schedule_id`
  and exists(select 1
             from `booking_role_schedule_talent` as `d`
             where `c`.`booking_role_schedule_id` <> `d`.`booking_role_schedule_id`
               and not (c.user_id != d.user_id))
where exists(select 1
             from `booking_role_schedules` as `b`
             where `a`.`id` <> `b`.`id`
               and not (a.start_date >= b.end_date or a.end_date <= b.start_date))
```

Comment: Why don't you use model relations plus has()/whereHas() ?

Comment: can you enlighten me, please?

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: I meant exactly what Amin linked, plus this: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: It is not an answer to your question, but it might help to know - you are using Laravel's query builder, *not* Eloquent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes sure.